# Click and drag scrolling using ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I would like to allow click and drag scrolling using a `ScrollViewer` (i.e. click anywhere in the `ScrollViewer` and drag up or down, and it will scroll accordingly)

I have a `StackPanel` nested inside a `ScrollViewer` and I already have the scrolling working. I believe I saw that answer somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

This has to be done using code only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [this code from Matt Hamilton](http://matthamilton.net/touchscrolling-for-scrollviewer):

```
public class TouchScrolling : DependencyObject
{
    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(TouchScrolling), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));

    static Dictionary<object, MouseCapture> _captures = new Dictionary<object, MouseCapture>();

    static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = d as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            target.Loaded += target_Loaded;
        }
        else
        {
            target_Unloaded(target, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }

    static void target_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Target Unloaded");

        var target = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        _captures.Remove(sender);

        target.Loaded -= target_Loaded;
        target.Unloaded -= target_Unloaded;
        target.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        target.PreviewMouseMove -= target_PreviewMouseMove;

        target.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    static void target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        _captures[sender] = new MouseCapture
        {
            VerticalOffset = target.VerticalOffset,
            Point = e.GetPosition(target),
        };
    }

    static void target_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Target Loaded");

        target.Unloaded += target_Unloaded;
        target.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        target.PreviewMouseMove += target_PreviewMouseMove;

        target.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    static void target_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        target.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    static void target_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_captures.ContainsKey(sender)) return;

        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            _captures.Remove(sender);
            return;
        }

        var target = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (target == null) return;

        var capture = _captures[sender];

        var point = e.GetPosition(target);

        var dy = point.Y - capture.Point.Y;
        if (Math.Abs(dy) > 5)
        {
            target.CaptureMouse();
        }

        target.ScrollToVerticalOffset(capture.VerticalOffset - dy);
    }

    internal class MouseCapture
    {
        public Double VerticalOffset { get; set; }
        public Point Point { get; set; }
    }
```

}

There are some quirks here. I noticed that the ScrollViewer was actually being loaded, unloaded and loaded again when the content was shown.

That meant that I couldn't just hook up the events in the `IsEnabledChanged` method and unhook them in the `target_Unloaded` event handler, because they were being unhooked immediately. Instead, I've had to hook them up in a handler for the Loaded event, which in turn never gets unhooked.

That means that there's something of a "memory leak" in there, but it's one I'm prepared to live with.

Comment: It causes memory leak, anyone have better one?